# Powershell error when running a hardware inventory script

Tags: powershell

When I run the following code I am getting an error at -computername -quiet -count1 saying that there is an issue with the **-properties operatingsystem | Select**. Full code below:

```
$Comps = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem | select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($Comp in $comps) {

if ((test-connection -ComputerName $Comp -Quiet -count 1 )) {

Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $Comp | select DeviceID,Name,Manufacturer,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors

}

else {

write-host  " $Comp Appears offline"

}

}
```

update: edited for new error
-properties : The term '-properties' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:1
+ -properties OperatingSystem | Select
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-properties:String) [], Command 
   NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-ExpandProperty : The term '-ExpandProperty' is not recognized as the name of 
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:4 char:1
+ -ExpandProperty Name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-ExpandProperty:String) [], Com 
   mandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Add a space between `-count` and `1` in that line

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the error message in the question.

Comment: Dont write a filter as a scriptblock. It should be a string like `-Filter "OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*'"`

Comment: Added new error, Theo error still exists with your change.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me:

```
$Comps = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem | select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($Comp in $comps) {

    if ((test-connection -ComputerName $Comp -Quiet -count 1 )) {

        Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $Comp | select SystemName,DeviceID,Name,Manufacturer,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation procs.csv -Append

    } else {

        write-host  " $Comp Appears offline"

    }
}
```

...I occasionally got Access Denied errors but It was working against some of the systems.  You should probably emit the computername with the processor information though or you'll have a tough time differentiating what hardware goes with what computer.

Comment: Yes! Seems like formatting was the issue. How do I output the data to a list?

Comment: See edits with the following changes:  Added SystemName property from Win32_processor and piped the output to CSV with the -Append switch so it would aggregate your results in the CSV.